# Migrate backbone to angular 6

Tags: javascript, java, angular, backbone.js, hybrid-mobile-app

Currently, my project is running on backbone js which is a hybrid application. So, I want to migrate the backbone Js application to angular 6 but I need specification Why angular is better than Backbone Js for building a hybrid application.

Comment: 1. "So, I want to migrate the backbone Js application".
2. "but I need specification Why angular is better than Backbone Js".

1. means you already have answer for 2.

Or is this more like "my colleague wants to do X but I want to prove him wrong"?
Either way, the answer would be opinion based which is not on-topic for this site afaik...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I see what you try to achieve here. IMHO As a JS-developer you should be able to answer most of this question by yourself. No framework or toolkit is perfect, neither are Backbone.js or Angular (or PhoneGap / Ionic / React (native) / you call it)! If you want to migrate your app to another language, ask yourself for which reasons you would do so: Do you simply want to learn another language? Or has Backbone.js proven to fail in certain situations/scenarios?

I did a hybrid-app project several years ago only using Backbone.js - and had no problems so far. However, if I would have to do the same job with more complex views, view-transitions, routes and all that mobile-related stuff, I'd probably choose a toolkit that can handle these scenarios much better and with less amount of code - such as Flutter, React native or even native programming. That is why you will first have to assess for yourself what your hybrid-app project really needs. Do you have to deal with heavy data? Then keep on using Backbone.js. Do you need two-way data-binding in forms? Well, that one goes to Angular. Or are parts of your code simply too verbose, un-testable or buggy? Then you should assume [refactoring your code](https://www.toptal.com/backbone-js/top-8-common-backbone-js-developer-mistakes) as much as possible instead of re-inventing the wheel.

A last word: There have been several discussions in the Backbone.js/Marionette.js community about how to migrate an app to framework xy. As a rule of thumb you should keep in mind that developing NEW components in another language / scripting style is way smarter that re-developing the entire app (which would, as a matter of fact, break a lot of your given business logic and lead to endless nights of doing the same thing over and over).